# Какие ограничения имеет сервлет вызванный через include()?

Tags: java, servlet

При использовании метода `include()` для временной передачи управления от сервлета `А` другому сервлету `В` есть ограничения в доступе к методам объектов `request` и `response`, внутри сервлета `В`. В том числе тем которые изменяют хедер запроса. Такие методы просто игнорируются.

Но это в общем. А хотелось бы иметь полный список методов на срабатывание которых не стоит рассчитывать при использовании `include()`.

Но самостоятельно мне не удалось этот перечень найти. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: `The included servlet cannot change the response status code or set headers; any attempt to make a change is ignored.` Другие ограничения не упоминаются. Этого вполне достаточно. Но если надо больше, то в спецификации по сервлетам наверняка есть детальное описание как должен работать servlet, request и response в том или ином случае.

Comment: @Sergey а что понимается под response status code? Я не могу ничего делать с объектом HttpServletResponse?

Comment: О status code https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP